# document.getelementbyClassName('select_wrapper') not working

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-7

I need your help.

I need to be able to provide support to IE7 to recognize the function `document.getElementbyClassName('select_wrapper')`

such that it can work in sync with the following coding:

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName('SELECT');

    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

            y[i].onblur = function() {
                this.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF'
                //document.getElementById('select_wrapper').style.backgroundColor = 'FFFFFF'
                getElementsByClassName('select_wrapper').style.backgroundColor = 'FFFFFF'
            }

            y[i].onfocusin = function() {
                this.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFC4'
                //document.getElementById('select_wrapper').style.backgroundColor = 'FFFFC4'
                getElementsByClassName('select_wrapper').style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFC4'
            }
    }
```

html:

Comment: I suggest using jQuery. It solves these compatibility layer issues.

Comment: Im new to jQuery, how would you tap into that and apply the coding?

Comment: jQuery is a utility written in JavaScript that not only solves a lot of these cross-browser features, but makes JavaScript easier to write by providing many shortcuts. It also has built-in AJAX functionality.

See: http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/intro/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use jQuery (http://jquery.com). Is Cross Browser and easy.

Comment: with jQuery you can do $(".SELECT").each(function(){ code... })

Comment: Surely he will use for more things